# Read local image file to img using HTML5 FileReader

Tags: jquery, html, image, filereader

I am trying to read local image file to img element. But `readAsDataURL()` seems to return "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```
var input = $('.mapimage_input').get(0);
console.log(input); // <input type="file" class="mapimage_input" accept="image/jpeg">
var file = input.files[0];
console.log(file); // File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Fri Mar 30 2012 12:32:03 GMT+0200, name: "avatar.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", size: 8724…}
var fr = new FileReader();
var img = fr.readAsDataURL(file);
console.log(img); // undefined
$('.mapimage_layer').attr('src',img);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`FileReader.readAsDataURL` is asynchronous.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29)

> Starts reading the contents of the specified `Blob` or `File`. When the read operation is finished, the `readyState` will become `DONE`, and the `onloadend` callback, if any, will be called. At that time, the `result` attribute contains a `data:` URL representing the file's data.

Attach an `onloadend` callback to the reader.

```
fr.onloadend = function() {
    var img = fr.result;                
    console.log(img);
    $('.mapimage_layer').attr('src',img);
}
```

Comment: Ok and how do I make a callback for that then?

Comment: there are some errors in the code above but I get it, will mark as answer as soon as possible

Comment: Fixed one thing - did I miss any others?

Comment: I think eveything is ok now, saw some people use `oneload` not `onloadend`, probably that is incorrect by them.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine to me!!

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

jQuery("#inputTypeFile").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to add some explanation to the answer.