# Issue in getting path of images

Tags: php, jquery, filereader

I am uploading multiple images and displaying them after select from input. But I can not get path of images using `FileReader`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="images" name="images" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="file" accept="image/*"  multiple>
            </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
               <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="upload">
            </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

      var images = $('#images')[0].files;
      var reader, file , i=0 , len=images.length;

     for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {

         if(window.FileReader){
          var file = $('#images').files[i];
          reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                        alert(e.target.result);
                        showimage(e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);       
           console.log();
         }
        }
     function showimage(source){

                    $('#img').append("<div class='col-sm-2'><img src="+src+" class='thumbnail hw'></img></div>");        
         }
});
```

I can not alert e.target.result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493869/read-local-image-file-to-img-using-html5-filereader

Answer (score 0):

Use reader.onload instead of reader.onloadend

Meanwhile, in your showImage(source) function, the parameter you passed was 'source' but you used 'src' in the function.

Comment: but it does not alert the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

      var images = $('#images')[0].files,
             input=$('#images').get(0) ; /*  need to add this  */
      var reader, file , i=0 , len=images.length;

     for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {

         if(window.FileReader){
          var file = input.files[i];
          reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                        alert(e.target.result);
                        showimage(e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);       
           console.log();
         }
        }
     function showimage(source){

                    $('#img').append("<div class='col-sm-2'><img src="+source+" class='thumbnail hw'></img></div>");        
         }
});
```